# How to extract a database based on a condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Please help me

The below one is the problem...

write an expression to extract a new dataframe containing those days where the temperature reached at least 70 degrees, and assign that to the variable at_least_70. (You might need to think some about what the different columns in the full dataframe represent to decide how to extract the subset of interest.)
After that, write another expression that computes how many days reached at least 70 degrees, and assign that to the variable num_at_least_70.

**This is the original DataFrame**

```
        Date  Maximum Temperature  Minimum Temperature  \
0    2018-01-01                    5                    0   
1    2018-01-02                   13                    1   
2    2018-01-03                   19                   -2   
3    2018-01-04                   22                    1   
4    2018-01-05                   18                   -2   
..          ...                  ...                  ...   
360  2018-12-27                   33                   23   
361  2018-12-28                   40                   21   
362  2018-12-29                   50                   37   
363  2018-12-30                   37                   24   
364  2018-12-31                   35                   25   

     Average Temperature  Precipitation  Snowfall  Snow Depth  
0                    2.5           0.04       1.0         3.0  
1                    7.0           0.03       0.6         4.0  
2                    8.5           0.00       0.0         4.0  
3                   11.5           0.00       0.0         3.0  
4                    8.0           0.09       1.2         4.0  
..                   ...            ...       ...         ...  
360                 28.0           0.00       0.0         1.0  
361                 30.5           0.07       0.0         0.0  
362                 43.5           0.04       0.0         0.0  
363                 30.5           0.02       0.7         1.0  
364                 30.0           0.00       0.0         0.0  

[365 rows x 7 columns]
```

**I wrote the code for the above problem is**`

```
at_least_70 = dfc.loc[dfc['Minimum Temperature']>=70,['Date']]
print(at_least_70)

num_at_least_70 = at_least_70.count()
print(num_at_least_70)
```

**The Results it is showing**

```
      Date
204  2018-07-24
240  2018-08-29
245  2018-09-03
Date    3
dtype: int64
```

But when run the test case it is showing...
Incorrect!
You are not correctly extracting the subset.

Comment: `write an expression to extract a new dataframe`. You extracted a `Series`. Remove `["Date"]` in the first line of your code.

Comment: Hi Henry, Thank you so much for editing my data, I tried to do that but I didn't get it.I changed the code as you guys suggested, but still, it is showing Incorrect!
You are not correctly extracting the subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @HenryYik, remove the column selector:

```
at_least_70 = dfc.loc[dfc['Maximum Temperature'] >= 70,
                      ['Date', 'Maximum Temperature']]
num_at_least_70 = len(at_least_70)
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thank you for your response, It didn't solve my problem, it is still showing the same error message.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Incorrect!
You are not correctly extracting the subset.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: that is the error message it is showing.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you have to select `Date` column and one or more `Temperature` columns?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I selected only the Maximum_temperature column and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for count `True`s of mask use `sum`:

```
mask = dfc['Minimum Temperature'] >= 70

at_least_70 = dfs[mask]
num_at_least_70 = mask.sum()
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you for your response,I tried this code but still it is showing same error message.